Starting with Qgis plugin development
I am trying to follow a course to learn how to develope plugins for QGIS.
But somehow it is not making sense.
I installed everything new, i also installed Ubuntu 24.04 new so everything is fresh.
On top i also installed QGIS and now i am trying to follow this course:
Course
This is the first problem i encounter:
1
But it is not making too much sense to me, because i am not familiar with all the terms.
I appreciate any help.
I tried to set up the environment for developing plugins and expected it to work like in the Tutorial

Try python3-pyqt5

The command you've tried to run (sudo apt-get install python-qt5) calls on Ubuntu's package manager (sort of like an appstore, but more advanced) to install the Qt 5 package for Python.
It could, however, not find a package by that name (python-qt5). Somewhat annoyingly, the names of packages sometimes slightly change between Ubuntu versions. In this case, you might want to try the python3-pyqt5 package as @couteau suggests.
